# SYBASE Cluster on RedHat Pacemaker Cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, redhat, sap-ase, pacemaker, sybase-ase15

I am trying to setup a SYBASE cluster on RedHat 7.5 using Pacemaker. I want the Active/Passive mode, where SYBASE will be running only in a single node a the time, but when I configure in such way it's work fine during the configuration, but when the standby node reboots the SYBASE resource is trying to get started on node 2 which it should not happen once it´s up and running on node 1.

I have configured Pacemaker as: 
- lvm-sybasedev-res and lvm-databasedev-res are there in order to give shared volume (iSCSI) access to the correct node where SYBASE will be running at the time. 
- The sybase-res resource has been created using the bellow command:

```
Resource Group: sybase-rg
     lvm-sybasedev-res  (ocf::heartbeat:LVM):   Started sdp-1
     lvm-databasedev-res        (ocf::heartbeat:LVM):   Started sdp-1
     sybase-IP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started sdp-1
     sybase-res (ocf::heartbeat:sybaseASE):     Started sdp-1

> pcs resource create sybase-res ocf:heartbeat:sybaseASE server_name="SYBASE" db_user="sa" \
db_passwd="password" sybase_home="/global/sdp/sybase" sybase_ase="ASE-15_0" \
sybase_ocs="OCS-15_0" interfaces_file="/global/sdp/sybase/interfaces" \              
sybase_user="sybase" --group sybase-rg --disable
```

I have constraint colocation setup in order to keep all resource under sybase-rg resoure group on the same node.

I was expecting that if the sybase-rg is up and running on node-1 (sdp-1)... even the node-2 (sdp-2) reboots it should not affect sybase-res because it's the inactive node which is rebooting.
Do I miss something? Any help is welcome.

Regards,

Comment: If you are using ASE CE then probably you should have SAP support. Have you created creating a SAP support case? What was their answer?

Comment: Hi @AdamLeszczyński. Unfortunately I don't have SAP support at the moment....